# How to get additional attributes in catalogProductReturnEntity in magento soap api

Tags: api, magento, soap

A list of content is given for **catalogProductReturnEntity** [Magento SOAP](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html)

I want  to get additional information like if product is configurable then associated simple products and configurable attribute.

How can I get these values?